# Matrix similarity comparisons among different floating point systems

Tags: linear-algebra

We are experimenting with the new tapered floating point system, called posits (https://posithub.org). One key aspect of the posit arithmetic is the use of a fused dot product operator, which yields only a single rounding event per dot product through the use of a super-accumulator, called the quire. In simple algebraic contexts, the super accumulator enables posits that are half the size of an IEEE floating point format to favorably compare in terms of accuracy. That is, a 32-bit posit yields similar precision as an IEEE double. The obvious idea is to use posits to make sparse linear algebra less memory bound.

We have a collection of iterative and direct solvers enabled with the fused dot product and we are comparing IEEE formats with posit formats by measuring the similarity to the identity matrix of expressions such as A^-1 * A = I.

Typical matrix similarities such as L1 norm and Frobenius norm require special attention to measure the similarity of these result matrices as their elements might differ by just a couple of ULPs, and thus the norms, in particular the L2 and Frobenius norms need to be calculated with double the precision, or use the quire to capture the minute differences.

Are there better measures of similarity that could be used to compare the numerical differences of number systems in the context of iterative and direct solvers?

I apologize that I can't tag the question with informative tags because I do not have enough reputation on this platform.

tags: ieee-floating-point, posit, error-analysis, matrix-similarity-measures

Comment: if folks want to get involved, all the software is developed as open source: https://github.com/stillwater-sc/universal